# Como obtener el valor de una variable en laravel cuando esta se encuentra mas abajo que donde la queremos

Tags: php, html, laravel, condiciones

quiero obtener el valor de una variable que esta mas abajo, el codigo se ve algo asi:

```
<p>{{ $list_index_1 }}</p>

@foreach ($clients_1 as $client_1)
  @if ($client_1->barber_key === $user->id)
    <p>{{ ++$list_index_1 }}. {{ $client_1->client_name }} -- {{ $client_1->client_cellphone_number }}</p>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Basicamente `$list_index_1` es el numero de clientes de la tienda, pero quiero obtener su ultimo valor para asi demostrarlo en el primer `<p>`. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Recomendaría hacer ese proceso en tu controlador. Y así sólo envías la data a la vista sin necesidad de hacer más que mostrar todo.

Comment: ¿`$clients_1` es un arreglo? Prueba a [contar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) cuántos elementos tiene.

Comment: Opino lo mismo que @JonatanLavado, desde el controlador manda una variable con el numero de clientes